# How to include/escape a single quote in field update?

Tags: workflow, field-update, escape

I've got a field update where I'd like to include a single quote, basically the contact's name and an apostrophe.

I've got it close with the following

```
Contact__r.Name + '\'s Submission'
```

This gets it to compile, but then it includes the `\` in the output, e.g. "Ralph\'s Solution"

Is there away to escape a single quote in a field update formula so that it doesn't print the escape character too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty easy, you can use double quotes in the formula values, which avoids the need to escape a single quote, e.g.

```
Contact__r.Name + "'s Submission"
```